# Microstrategy Lookup Table join

Tags: microstrategy

1. Lookup table (State)
   In this table I have 4 Columns (Region_id,RegionName,State_id,State_name)
   2.Fact table
   In this I have couple of Columns like(customer,product,date,Region_id,State_id,Revenue, Profit)

In lookup table there are more number of states whereas in fact we have data only for few states.

My requirement is to display all the sates in report even though there is no corresponding data available in fact.i have set the state table as lookup for state attribute.
If I pull the state attribute and a metric from fact and set vldb properties preserve lookup table then I'm getting all the sates and it's metric values and null for the one which don't have metric value.

Now If I add some attribute like customer or product along with it I'm not getting all the sates..I'm getting only the states which have data in fact since on adding some attribute the mstr is not hitting state table at all it's bringing data from fact itself.

What could be done so tat I can get all the sates and null even for the customer and product..?

Answer (score 0):

You could try forcing your metrics to outer-join on the dataset itself while preserving final pass elements to make a left join.

Within developer, navigate to your dataset/cube and open it up in editable mode.
Select "Data" within the top bar of the cube/dataset editor >> Report Data Options >> Metric Join Type.

Here you will see your Metrics. Change the join type from inner to outer. Rerun the report and it should bring back all the data you need.

Let me know how it goes.